# Trouble with JavaScript based photo gallery

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to adapt the HTML, CSS, an JavaScript from here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow_gallery.asp

The problem I'm having is I would like to have all the JavaScript in the JS file and none be in the html.

When I try to move the onclick out of the HTML and into the JS file I have had nothing but problems. Beginning with the DOM not being loaded(solved with a domLoaded function) then to a problem with event listeners for the individual pictures.

My current problem is that the slides in the showSlides function is undefined if I pass the number 1 through it, either as you see in the document.querySelector or if I call the currentSlides or showSlides function in the console.

```js
//waits for the DOM to load so that everything is ready for the gallery code. 
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", domLoaded);

function domLoaded() {
  showSlides(slideIndex);
}

document.querySelector("#img1").addEventListener("click", currentSlide.bind(1));
document.querySelector("#img2").addEventListener("click", currentSlide.bind(2));
document.querySelector("#img3").addEventListener("click", currentSlide.bind(3));
document.querySelector('#img4').addEventListener("click", currentSlide.bind(4));
document.querySelector('#img5').addEventListener("click", currentSlide.bind(5));
document.querySelector('#img6').addEventListener("click", currentSlide.bind(6));
//Begin w3schools gallery code

var slideIndex = 1;
// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  console.log("click working")
  let i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  let captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";

  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";

  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number text -->
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
    <img class="mainImage" src="assets/dancingSnow.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 6</div>
    <img class="mainImage" src="assets/CABELL CO TOURNEY 2016.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 6</div>
    <img class="mainImage" src="assets/IMG_9320.JPG">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 6</div>
    <img class="mainImage" src="assets/Invitation.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">5 / 6</div>
    <img class="mainImage" src="assets/SCAbattleline.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">6 / 6</div>
    <img class="mainImage" src="assets/Yorick Paragon Druid.jpg">
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

  <!-- Image text -->
  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
  </div>

  <!-- Thumbnail images -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="assets/dancingSnow.jpg" id="img1" alt="Dancing in the Snow">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="assets/CABELL CO TOURNEY 2016.jpg" id="img2" alt="Cabell Co Tourney 2016">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="assets/IMG_9320.JPG" id="img3" alt="unknown">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="assets/Invitation.jpg" id="img4" alt="Invitation">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="assets/SCAbattleline.jpg" id="img5" alt="Ready for War">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="assets/Yorick Paragon Druid.jpg" id="img6" alt="Amtgard Award">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your bind solution, `plusSlides` function works incorrectly. If you put `console.log(n)` inside you'll see that n is not a number but rather `[object PointerEvent]`, and so your `slideIndex` gets messed up and breaks `showSlides` function. The first argument of `bind` is usually the `this` pointer and you have to offset your desired arguments by one. You can pass null as the first argument, like this:

```
document.querySelector("#img1").addEventListener("click", currentSlide.bind(null,1));
```

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/progmars/njwo0ct7/

However, it could be so much cleaner with jQuery and better model separation from view.

Comment: I found a solution. Added six of these to the domLoaded function.
```document.querySelector("#img1").addEventListener("click", () => currentSlide(1));```

I'm just starting out and the course limits what we should be using. jQuery hasn't been covered yet.

Comment: @DrewS  yes, `() => currentSlide(1)` is also a good - more modern - alternative to `bind(null...`